# Связанное удаление данных из ListBox'а

Tags: delphi

Как проверить эти 2 листбокса и те числа, которые есть во втором листбоксе, удалились в первом.

Delphi... Вот есть у меня 2 listbox`a, с items :

```
В первом: 
1 
10 
100500

во втором:
1
5
100500
```

Надо, чтобы прога проверила эти 2 листбокса и те числа, которые есть во втором листбоксе удалились в первом, то есть в листбокс 1 должно остаться только "10"

Comment: @Maykop, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Поэлементно двумя циклами(вложенными) сравнить оба листбокса, и удалить повторяющиеся элементы из первого лисбокса.
Если автор покажет что у него не получилось - помогу исправить ошибку.

Comment: Всем кто захочет написать автору готовый код, предлогаю глянуть историю его вопросов....

Comment: и то, что у него 0% принятых ответов.

Comment: минус за то, что ни одного ответа не принял